# What is the best way to wrap resultset data and transfer as DTO?

Tags: jakarta-ee

I'm a novice in to this project world. Currently I'm facing some difficulties with my project to retrieve and display last three assessment details. I made a database query and obtained the following resultset :

```
date     assmnt_id    topic_name     full_mark   tot_ques   tot_obtn_mark    tot_corr_ans    
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
12/12/12     1001        oops            15        15             10              10
12/12/12     1001        thread          10        10             08              08
12/12/12     1001       collection       15        15             08              08
13/12/12     1002         oops           20        20             15              15
13/12/12     1002       thread           20        20             15              15
13/12/12     1002         IO             10        10             07              07
14/12/13     1003       string           15        15             12              12
14/12/13     1003         IO             10        10             05              05
```

I have taken one DTO which contain all the mark related fields and then stored in to `Map<String, TopicDetails>`. I took the topic name as the key and the corresponding DTO as value.

My required output is:

> user should be able to get the details of his/her last 3 assessment

```
12/12/12  {oops,15,15,10,10
           thread,10,10,08,08
            .......}
13/12/12  {oops,20,20,15,15
           thread,20,20,15,15
            .......}
```

My DTOs contain:

```
// TopicDetails
int full_mark;
int tot_ques;
int tot_obtn_mark;
int tot_corr_ans;

//AssessmentDTO
String name;
Map<String, TopicDetails> details;
```

Somehow I'm getting the output but not exactly. I want to know the best possible solution for it.

Comment: Not enough info. What persistence framework in which version do you use?

Comment: I'm using  jdk 6 with no persistence framework. Simply I'have taken JDBC, as it is given as a requirement to me. I want to know the DTO format which I've taken is correct or any other alternative way I can also achieve the same.